# Tweaking the Fill Factor to reduce fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing, fillfactor

I have an non-clustered index that has ~1000 pages, 95% fragmentation and a FillFactor of '0'.

I rebuilt the index on Sunday. A week later, the index has 95% (or so) fragmentation again. Is this an indication that I need to change the FillFactor to say 80-90%?

Should I be tweaking the fill factor each week to see if I can reduce the fragmentation from week to week? Is there a target level I shoot be shooting for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would consider tweaking your fill factor for sure.  If it's fragmenting quickly, I'm guessing it's a write-heavy index, which can gain substantial performance benefits from a fill factor.

Determing optimal fill factors is pretty much a trial-and-error process though, and more of an art than a science.  From [Tips for Rebuilding Indexes by Brad McGehee](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/rebuilding_indexes_p1.aspx):

> So what is the ideal fill factor? It
>   depends on the ratio of reads to
>   writes that your application makes to
>   your SQL Server tables. As a rule of
>   thumb, follow these guidelines:
>
> ```
> * Low Update Tables (100-1 read to write ratio): 100% fill factor
> * High Update Tables (where writes exceed reads): 50%-70% fill factor
> * Everything In-Between: 80%-90% fill factor.
> ```

Comment: Gern - you can query sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats - it has columns for "user_seeks", "user_scans" and "user_lookups", as well as "user_updates".  Check here for a neat query to tie it all together into a nice ratio number: http://statisticsio.com/Home/tabid/36/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/324/Is-8020-a-90rsquos-Estimate.aspx

Comment: For a fuller explanation of the pros and cons of fill factor, read Kendra Little's article at http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/ - take particular notice of her recommendation to get a decent index maintenance solution.